# An inequality regarding Beta function/Gamma functions.

Tags: inequality, gamma-function, beta-function

Is there a way to mathematically show that

$$ \frac{1}{q} > 2^q \left( \frac{\Gamma(q)\Gamma(q+1)}{\Gamma(2q+1)} \right)$$

for all $1 < q < \infty$? This is true by plotting this on Mathematica/Desmos, but I can't seem to find an analytic proof for this. I have also noticed that $\left( \frac{\Gamma(q)\Gamma(q+1)}{\Gamma(2q+1)} \right)$ is nothing but $\text{Beta}(q,q+1)$ but I can't seem to find any relevant facts that I can use to prove this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Would $$
B(q,q + 1) = \int_0^1 {t^q (1 - t)^{q - 1} dt}  = \int_0^1 {t(t(1 - t))^{q - 1} dt}  \le \int_0^1 {t\frac{1}{{4^{q - 1} }}dt}  \le \frac{1}{{4^{q - 1} }}
$$ help? Then at least for $q>2$, $$
2^q B(q,q + 1) \le \frac{1}{{2^{q - 1} }} < \frac{1}{q}.
$$

Comment: It might help if I can think along these lines to generalize this to arbitrary $$q > 1$$ but I'll think a little more about it; thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $q > 2$, see @Gary's comment.

When $1 < q \le 2$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\Gamma(q)\Gamma(q + 1)}{\Gamma(2q + 1)} &=
 \int_0^1 t^q (1 - t)^{q - 1}\mathrm{d} t \\
 &= \int_0^{1/2} t^q (1 - t)^{q - 1}\mathrm{d} t
 + \int_{1/2}^1 t^q (1 - t)^{q - 1}\mathrm{d} t \\
 &= \int_0^{1/2} t^q (1 - t)^{q - 1}\mathrm{d} t
 + \int_0^{1/2} (1 - t)^q t^{q - 1}\mathrm{d} t \\
 &= \int_0^{1/2} t^{q- 1} (1 - t)^{q - 1}\mathrm{d} t\\
 &\le \int_0^{1/2} t^{q- 1} (1 - (q - 1)t)\mathrm{d} t\\
 &= \frac{-q^2 + 3q + 2}{2^{q + 1}q (q + 1)}
\end{align*}
where we have used Bernoulli inequality to get $(1 - t)^{q - 1}
\le 1 - (q - 1)t$. Thus, we have
$$q 2^q \frac{\Gamma(q)\Gamma(q + 1)}{\Gamma(2q + 1)}
\le \frac{-q^2 + 3q + 2}{2 (q + 1)} < 1.$$

We are done.

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks!

Comment: @HKTan You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$2^q\,\frac{ \Gamma (q)\, \Gamma (q+1)}{\Gamma (2 q+1)}=2^{-q}\sqrt{\pi } \frac{ \Gamma (q)}{\Gamma \left(q+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$  I suppose that you can easily show it  using induction (the equality is for $q=1$).

If you want to use algebra, consider the function
$$f(q)=\log \left(\frac{1}{q}\right)-\log\Bigg[2^{-q}\sqrt{\pi } \frac{ \Gamma (q)}{\Gamma \left(q+\frac{1}{2}\right)} \Bigg]$$ for which
$$f'(q)=-\frac{1}{q}-\psi (q)+\psi \left(q+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\log (2)$$ is always positive. Moreover $f(1)=0$ and $f'(1)=1-\log(2)$.

Concerning the function
$$g(q)=\frac 1 q - \Bigg[2^{-q}\sqrt{\pi } \frac{ \Gamma (q)}{\Gamma \left(q+\frac{1}{2}\right)} \Bigg]$$ you could easily show that its maximum is very close to $q=\sqrt {10}$ and $g(\sqrt {10})\sim \frac 15$

Comment: I think the induction argument might work for me, thanks!